# Send commands from MS-windows to linux by plink

Tags: linux

This is my script which is run on windows. The script connect to linux and do many commands, for instance:

1. stops the server
2. unzips new one
3. starts the new

```
plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword /bin/bash /opt/server/stop.sh
plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword rm -R /opt/server/ --force
plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword unzip /opt/server.zip -d /opt/
plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword /bin/bash /opt/server/start.sh
```

How can I send the commands with in one `plink`?

Something like:

```
plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword /bin/bash /opt/server/stop.sh 
  & rm -R /opt/server/ --force 
  & unzip /opt/server.zip -d /opt/ 
  & /bin/bash /opt/server/start.sh
```

Comment: Maybe it's not directly responds to your question, but have you thought of using some management tool for these tasks (like Ansible or Bolt)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I **strongly** advise against using clients that take passwords on the command line. If you don't want to type in the password create a keypair and use that to login.

But this should be discussed somewhere else, let's stick to your question. You have 2 options:

1. `plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword sh -c "/opt/server/stop.sh && rm -R /opt/server/ --force && unzip /opt/server.zip -d /opt/ && /opt/server/start.sh"`
2. Create a script `myscript.sh` that does the things you want to do and use `plink -batch proksys@11.111.111.11 -P 22 -l root -pw mypassword myscript.sh`

Notice that I use `&&` instead of `&` everywhere. The difference:

- `something &` runs `something` as background process (probably not what you wanted to do.
- `something && nextthing` runs `something` and only runs `nextthing` if `something` has a returncode of 0 (which usually means the same as `something` finished without large problems)